# The limit as $n \to \infty$ of $\big[\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1 + \frac{k}{n})\big]^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I think the limit should be $=1$ because
$$\bigg[ \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1 + \frac{k}{n})\bigg]^{1/n} = \exp \bigg[ \frac{1}{n} \big[ \log(1 + \frac{1}{n}) + \cdots + \log2 \big] \bigg] =\\ \exp \bigg[ \frac{1}{n} \big[ o(1) + \cdots + o(1) + \log 2 \big] \bigg] = 1 + o(1)\big|_{n \to \infty}.$$
Is there an error in the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. It would be better to think of $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \log\Big( 1+ \frac{k}{n} \Big)$$ as a Riemann sum for $\log(1+x)$ over $[0,1].$ The integral $\int_0^1 \log(1+x)\, \mathrm{d}x$ is not zero, so this limit is not $1$.

Comment: You can delete answers, you know.

Comment: Thanks. I think I know where I am wrong. The behaviors of the middle logs are not clear enough to conclude.